# Python 3: capture image

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I am trying to capture an image from my web camera on windows using Python 3.
I checked already openCV, but the support of python-3 is missing.

Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: [opencv 3.0 supports Python 3](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/3.0.0-alpha) (final release should be available  in the next year). You don't need opencv to get a picture from your webcam.

Comment: possible duplicate of [taking webcam photos in python 3 and windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175486/taking-webcam-photos-in-python-3-and-windows)

Comment: Following J.F. Sebastian's comment, I can offer an update that [as of 4 June 2015](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0.html), a production version of OpenCV with Python 3.x bindings is at last available.

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime, OpenCV 3.1 was released and works with Python 3 (since OpenCV 3.0). Pre-compiled Windows binaries can be found here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Answer (score 1):

you can try OpenCV, SimpleCV.

```
using SimpleCV:

from SimpleCV import Image, Camera

cam = Camera()
img = cam.getImage()
img.save("filename.jpg")
```

using OpenCV:

```
from cv2 import *
# initialize the camera
cam = VideoCapture(0)   # 0 -> index of camera
s, img = cam.read()
if s:    # frame captured without any errors
    namedWindow("cam-test",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    imshow("cam-test",img)
    waitKey(0)
    destroyWindow("cam-test")
    imwrite("filename.jpg",img) #save image
```

using pygame:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera

pygame.camera.init()
pygame.camera.list_camera() #Camera detected or not
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img,"filename.jpg")
```

Install OpenCV:

```
install python-opencv bindings, numpy
```

Install SimpleCV:

```
install python-opencv, pygame, numpy, scipy, simplecv
```

get latest version of [SimpleCV](https://github.com/ingenuitas/simplecv/downloads)

Install pygame:

```
install pygame
```

Comment: I am using windows. I tried `SimpleCV`, but could not install it `pip3 install -U SimpleCV` says that it was successfully installed, but when importing it I got `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`