# Python: Access camera WITHOUT OpenCV

Tags: python, macos, camera

Comrades,

I'd like to capture images from the laptop camera in Python.  Currently all signs point to OpenCV.  Problem is OpenCV is a nightmare to install, and it's a nightmare that reoccurs every time you reinstall your code on a new system.

Is there a more lightweight way to capture camera data in Python?  I'm looking for something to the effect of:

```
$ pip install something
$ python
>>> import something
>>> im = something.get_camera_image()
```

I'm on Mac, but solutions on any platform are welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11094891/5008845

Comment: Not directly answer to **without** but if you have problem installing OpenCV for Windows you could try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv whl binary package

Answer (score 3):

I've done this before using [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml). But I can't seem to find the script that I used... It seems there is a tutorial [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html) which uses the native camera module and is not dependent on OpenCV.

Try this:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/path/to/camera",(640,480))
cam.start()

image = cam.get_image()
```

If you don't know the path to the camera you can also get a list of all available which should include you laptop webcam:

```
camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
    if camlist:
        cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0],(640,480))
```

Comment: Hmm, at least on my pygame install I get `File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/camera.py"`, `line 42, in init`
    `import _camera`
`ImportError: No module named _camera` on the `camera.init()` line.

Comment: Interesting, try edited answer. Changed the imports to what the tutorial has written.

Comment: Still the same, but this may be something to do with me not having properly installed pygame.

Answer (score 3):

As [the documentation states](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html), currently  `pygame.camera` only supports linux and v4l2 cameras, so this would not work on macOS. On Linux instead it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pyavfcam [github](https://github.com/dashesy/pyavfcam). You will need to install xcode and cython,  first. This is the official demo.

```
import pyavfcam

# Open the default video source
cam = pyavfcam.AVFCam(sinks='image')
cam.snap_picture('test.jpg')

print "Saved test.jpg (Size: " + str(cam.shape[0]) + " x " + str(cam.shape[1]) + ")"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Videocapture for Windows

I've used [videocapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) in the past and it was perfect:

```
from VideoCapture import Device
cam = Device()
cam.saveSnapshot('image.jpg')
```