# How do I get images from webcam without using OpenCV?

Tags: python, pycharm

The library used in the project does not work with OpenCV.Therefore I need to trade without using OpenCV.
Which module should I use for this? To take images from the camera?

I'm using python 3
Thankyou.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Access camera WITHOUT OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003106/python-access-camera-without-opencv)

Comment: I think this is both entirely off-topic and low effort.

Answer (score 2):

or you can use [SimpleCV](https://simplecv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from SimpleCV import Image, Camera

cam = Camera()
img = cam.getImage()
img.save("filename.jpg")
```

Comment: I'm using python 3

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the OS you are using. You can try with `pygame.camera`, `VideoCapture` - http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/, or `pyavfcam` - https://github.com/dashesy/pyavfcam.